# Source to comfort mourners "המקום ינחם אתכם"

Tags: sources-mekorot, mourning-aveilus

What is the original source to comfort mourners with the exact phrase "המקום ינחם אתכם בתוך שאר אבלי ציון וירושלים" - "*hamakom* (the Omnipresent, i.e., God) should comfort you among the mourners of Zion and Yerushalayim?

I understand this is not an early Minhag but many of the sources I've seen quoted as being the source actually have a different text. I am looking for the words of המקום ינחם אתכם explicitly.

Edit: There is a similar question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68812/source-for-hamakom-said-at-shiva-and-variations) but due to the way it was asked, the answer that was given answered the question without actually providing a source for the full text of "המקום ינחם אתכם בתוך שאר אבלי ציון וירושלים". I am looking for the source of that phrase specifically as I wrote. Not one word from the phrase, the entire phrase. Thanks.

Comment: in case you're wondering about the word אתכם https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17046/759

Comment: I'm not. See my comment there. No source is provided there for "המקום ינחם אתכם בתוך שאר אבלי ציון וירושלים". The Prisha there is misquoted. The author saw it misquoted in the article and presumably assumed it was quoted correctly.

Comment: So a source for "המקום ינחם אותך בתוך שאר אבלי ציון וירושלים" would not suffice?

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, but if someone were to find it, I would like to see it inside anyways.